# How to detect an error outside of the windows element (appium / c#)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have an issue, with the app I'm working, that every time an error occurred it goes outside of the app as u can see in the image I upload, and every time I try to find it with the appium.webdriver nuget package, on visual studio (C#), it cant find it because its outside of the original app, its there any way to find the error? [Error outside original app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDrrw.png)

I was trying solving it with coordinates and click but the coordinates are not the same every time so it doesn't work all the time